# Return object key names having value of true as comma delimited string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object with different properties, I need to return a string only for specific properties = true

```
{
    cash: true,
    cashless: true,
    credit: (4)[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}],
    gift: true,
    stamp: true,
    stamp_number: 10,
    stamp_reward: "Free tea",
    terms_and_conditions: "Terms & Conditions",
    tier_type: "visits",
    upfront: false
}
```

I need to keep track of the properties: gift, stamp and upfront
In this case it should return a string = Gift, Stamp

Comment: I have this code that filters by name, but I need it to filter only the true ones. 

const result = arr
    .filter((prop) => prop === 'gift' || prop === 'upfront' || prop === 'cash')
    .map(function(string) {
      return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1)
    })
    .join(', ')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to return *certain* proper-cased key names for properties, having value `true`, you may

- extract key names with [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- filter those based on whether respective value is `true` and they belong to target keys list (using [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
- traverse resulting list with [`Array.prtototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to apply proper-casing
- join resulting array into string with [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join#:%7E:text=The%20join()%20method%20creates,returned%20without%20using%20the%20separator.)

```js
const src = {
    cash: true,
    cashless: true,
    credit: [],
    gift: true,
    stamp: true,
    stamp_number: 10,
    stamp_reward: "Free tea",
    terms_and_conditions: "Terms & Conditions",
    tier_type: "visits",
    upfront: false
},

    result = Object
      .keys(src)
      .filter(key => ['gift', 'stamp', 'upfront'].includes(key) && src[key] === true)
      .map(key => `${key[0].toUpperCase()}${key.slice(1)}`)
      .join(', ')
      
console.log(result)
```